# How can I use all space available in a Grid?

Tags: wpf

I have a horizontal ListView and I want it to use all available horizontal space. I cannot get it to work and I assume I am missing something fundamental. The button in the code below should stretch all the way up.

This is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="tt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tt"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="200">

<Grid Background="Blue">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="5" Background="AliceBlue">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button>xx</Button>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding}" Margin="20"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding}" Margin="20"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the code (providing the data):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<String> MyData { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyData = new ObservableCollection<string>() {
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve"
        };
        DataContext = this;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is snapped to the bottom because of this line:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
```

If you want the scrollviewer to fill the entire window, try this instead:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```